# Theme Splash Image within the "Appearance -> Themes" control panel

Tags: theme-development, themes

I have created a theme, and its all working fine.

Within the WordPress control panel under **"Appearance -> Themes"**, you can see the available themes *(Twenty Fourteen, Twenty Thirteen etc etc)* and they all have a splash image demonstrating what your blog could look like.

My theme just shows a blank canvas. Is there a way of adding an image or something to represent my theme?

I bet I have missed something really obvious. :/

Comment: Deja-vu :-). Everything is handled in the duplicate

Comment: Checking it out now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those themes there's a screenshot.png or screenshot.jpg that gets used. I would recommend using an 880x660px image ( for the aspect ratio, and for retina displays )

Comment: Ahh ok! So where do you put that .png file and how do you reference it?

Comment: Just seen there is a link to a previous question that was similar.. I will check that out and report back.

Comment: You don't reference it, place it in your themes folder adjacent to index.php etc, and it's automatically picked up